# Mongodb data is not returned to nodejs api

Tags: angularjs, node.js, mongodb

I am able to connect to mongodb through my nodejs api but for some reason data is not returned. When i query mongodb from console , here is what i get :

```
MongoDB Enterprise > db.patients.find();
{ "_id" : ObjectId("58c9a5dd1eb8c7c1c68778ca"), "FName" : "n", "LName" : "ri", "Email" : "abc@yahoo.com", "phone" : "1234567890" }
```

here is the code from nodejs:

```
app.get('/api/patients',function(req,res){
    Patient.getPatients(function(err,patients){
        if(err){
            throw err;
        }
        console.log(patients.length);
        res.json(patients);

    });
});
```

and this is getPatients method:

```
var Patient = module.exports = mongoose.model('patient',patientSchema);

// get patients

module.exports.getPatients = function(callback,limit){

    Patient.find(callback);
}
```

But the browser always shows "[]" and no data. When i look at length of array ( console.log(patients.length)) in API , i get 0. Not sure why data is not returned.
Can someone pls point me what may be the issue ?

**Update**

Based on suggestions, I did following changes. I created 2 collections just to make sure that the collection exists. So i have patient and patients collections.

```
MongoDB Enterprise > db.patient.find();
{ "_id" : ObjectId("58cfe4551eb8c7c1c68778cc"), "FName" : "V", "LName" : "K", "Email" : "abc@yahoo.com", "phone" : "1234567890" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("58cfe4601eb8c7c1c68778cd"), "FName" : "V1", "LName" : "K1", "Email" : "abc@yahoo.com", "phone" : "1234567890" }
MongoDB Enterprise > db.patients.find();
{ "_id" : ObjectId("58cfe42d1eb8c7c1c68778cb"), "FName" : "V", "LName" : "K", "Email" : "abc@yahoo.com", "phone" : "1234567890" }
```

Here is the code from nodejs file:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

var patientSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    FName: {
        type : String
     },
     LName: {
        type : String
     },

     Email: {
        type : String
     },
     phone: {
        type : String
     },

},
{collection : 'patient'});


var Patient = module.exports = mongoose.model('patient',patientSchema);

// get patients

module.exports.getPatients = function(callback,limit){
console.log('test2');
 Patient.find({}, function(err, patients) {
  if (err) throw err;

  // object of all the users
  console.log(patients.length);
});
}
```

when i run this code, it prints 'test2' and '0' for me but not actual results. Can someone help with this ?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you defined your schemas well and its exported very well... If yes then do something like this from your nodejs scripts

```
//get the model 
var Patient = mongoose.model('patient',patientSchema);
// get all the patients
Patient.find({}, function(err, patients) {
  if (err) throw err;

  // object of all the users
  console.log(patients);
});
```

I believe this should work

Comment: Can you push your code to github, I can clone it and solve the problem.. ?

Comment: https://github.com/justdev123/Mean  -> It may be a big project but relevant files are 1) src\models\patient.js  2) app.js

Comment: I will come the repo and set it up when I get home... That shouldn't be too difficult for me to solve

Answer (score 0):

The answer above, while executing the find on the Patient model correctly, will not get the results back to your api response. I think if you change your getPatients code to this:

```
var Patient = module.exports = mongoose.model('patient',patientSchema);

module.exports.getPatients = function(callback) {
    Patient.find({},
        function(err, data) {
            callback(err,data);
        }
    );
}
```

It will work. If that doesn't work, I'd want to see the entire code file to make sure the app.get can access the getPatients function - but you would get an error if that wasn't the case. So, I think this will work.

Answer (score 0):

I figured my code was correct but connection string was incorrect.

Incorrect Connection string :

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/');

Correct connection string:

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/**patients**');